# Load different header images depending on media queries

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have built a header which consists only of an image, which, at the same time, is a link to my home page:

```
<header>
    <div class="headerimg">
    <a href="./index.html">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="headerwide.jpg" alt="Koerpertherapie Header"></a>
    </div>
</header>
```

Now, I also have another image "headersmall.jpg", which I would like to load on smartphones. I could of course create two different divs, with classes "headerimgwide" and "headerimgsmall", and only show one, depending on a media query, but as far as I understand it, that would cause the browser to load both images everytime. Is there another way, without loading the unnecessary image?

Answer (score 1):

you could set the image as a background image and change the image path according to the media query

```
<header>
    <div class="headerimg">
    <a href="./index.html">
    </a>
    </div>
</header>
```

and css

```
.headerimg > a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%; /*or whatever fits your need*/
    height: 100%; /*or whatever fits your need*/
    background: url('/images/small_image.jpg') center center cover no-repeat;
}
@media (min-width: 600px){
    background-image: url('/images/large_image.jpg');
}
```

Comment: Ahhh I was just about to post my answer with a similar set up. Well I have already made a [fiddle if anyone is interested](https://jsfiddle.net/bcrcn12b/).

Comment: I'm sorry I keep asking stupid questions, but the problem is now that my header has a height of 0. I do not want to set an absolute height, since the header will become emptier when the background image scales. I set width to 100% and height to auto, what would I need to do to have the whole thing adjust to the image size like it did before moving the image to the css?

Comment: I think the problem is, that I do not want to have any content except for the image, and thus if I move the image to the css as background image, it's empty.

Comment: that is why I added the comment in the css:
/*or whatever fits your need*/

Comment: The problem is, I am not sure, if what I want to achieve is even possible, which is why I asked the question. What would I need to add as width and height in your opinion, to make the div fit the size of the background image, which should scale depending on the screen width?